# Is there any difference between these sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction

What’s the difference between these two sentences and which one is the correct one?

> 1. A tsunami devastated the coast of Japan and caused the meltdown at a nuclear power plant.
> 2. A tsunami devastated the coast of Japan and causing the meltdown at a nuclear power plant.

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Do you think either of them is incorrect? What research have you done? These are things you should mention in your question.

Comment: Did you want to say "devastated"?

Comment: Hint: both verbs should be in the same form.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Oh, I see.